# I can not export my database table in PDF on live host

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

I can export my database table in Localhost. But when I keep my code on Host, Below warning wiill fire. Let me know how I solve this warning.

> PHP Warning:  fopen(shotdev/Field_Work_Report.pdf): failed to open stream: Permission denied in D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\econhealthcare.net\httpdocs\econ2\pdf\fpdf.php on line 1044

Comment: does the `shotdev/Field_Work_Report.pdf` exist? what is the permission?

Comment: Yep, You are right. I had to change permissions. Thank You Mr. Raptor.

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments above, the issue is fixed by changing the permission to correct settings, as the error message suggested that it's due to Permission errors.